# Getting and error called Invalid Hook call in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import "./Searchbar.css"
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import MicIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mic';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Searchbar() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const[input, setInput] = useState('');
   

    const search = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        // when the click enter button 
        
        history.push("/search")
    }

    return (
        <form className="search">
            <div className="search_box">
                <SearchIcon className="search_icon" />
                <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
                <MicIcon />
            </div>

            <div className="search_cards">
               <Button type='submit' onClick={search} variant="outlined">Google Search</Button>
               <Button variant="outlined">I'm Feeling Lucky</Button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

export default Searchbar;
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

this is the my code. i have tried to use **useHistory** hook to redirect to the searchpage when i have clicked that search button.

but after adding Use History hook it displays message like

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

is it wrong that the way i have called **useHistory** hook???

[Github repo](https://github.com/Dimuthu-10/temp-site)

Comment: Your component looks good, Look for other places you use hooks.

Comment: sorry. i can't understand what you say.

Comment: You can use `useHistory` in APP where you define your write and pass as props then you can use.

Comment: hooks are supposed to be on top of any component. It can't be parts of other blocks like if/for loop or a method. Your code looks good and can't see the same code in your Github though !!

Comment: @AKX now i have added. it is in home branch

Comment: Error could be due to your usage of this component. You should use components with Hooks as Components only and not as functions.
So while using it, try using those as `<Searchbar />` and not as `{Searchbar()}`.

Comment: @DimuthuLakshan I checked out your repo. You're missing the `react-router` and `react-router-dom` dependencies (did you `npm i` instead of `npm i --save`?), but after installing those, I'm not getting that error at all.

Comment: i have already installed that dependencies. i will try again.

Comment: @AKX i have added my dependencies to the main question.

Comment: Thank you all guys. specially @AKX. i have tried with different versions of react router dom. then i have found it works with version 5.0. now my app is working very well. thank you all for your contribution.